# How to perform custom persistence of variables in a WF4 Workflow?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I would like to override the default persistence of custom objects used as variables and arguments in a Workflow Foundation 4 workflow. I understand that WF4 persists custom objects using the  NetDataContractSerializer.

However, my objects are not simple POCOs. They are more like "ActiveRecord" objects, linked to a database. Therefore, I would like to override the persistence process, in order to store those objects into and load those objects from the database as required

I have tried implementing ISerializable but, obviously, it does not work.
Is there another extension point in Workflow Foundation where I can plug into so that I can intercept and customize the persistence behaviour of my custom objects?

For instance, imagine the following object:

```
public sealed class Entity
{
    private readonly SqlConnection connection_;

     public Guid Id { get; private set; }
     public String Name { get; set; }

     // I would like to persist this object in the database
     // when the workflow "asks" for it to be persisted
     // I don't know what to write or implement in this class
}
```

How could this object be persisted in the database automatically when the Workflow persists or unloads. In my case, the SqlConnection is not serializable so I should probably write some custom code, implement ISerializable or something.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PersistenceParticipant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.persistence.persistenceparticipant(v=vs.110).aspx) to provide additional information to your persisted workflow instance. Data for PersistenceParticipant can come from sources other than the workflow. You register PersistenceParticipant as extension that can be added later, you can extend data that need to be stored
per workflow instance

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Could you be a bit more specific. I updated my question and have added an example of a POCO entity I would like to persist in the database.

Comment: If your entity acts like a process variable, it's not directly participate in persistance, so you can't add some code for persistance in the entity itself. Like I wrote before, you need to implement PersistanceParticipant, register it as workflow extension and in its implementation you can customize persisting of your entity. Please follow those links for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473464(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829475(v=vs.110).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364726(v=vs.110).aspx